# How to print HTML entities using String.Format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have something like this inside my View:

```
@String.Format("{0} &copy; Copyright by Nemanja", DateTime.Now.Year);
```

However, this is escaping my `&` into `&amp;`. Is there any way to bypass this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for `@Html.Raw(...)`, which will prevent that and create an XSS hole instead.

In your case, you can get rid of it entirely:

```
@DateTime.Now.Year &copy; Copyright by Nemanja
```

Answer (score 5):

You can:

```
@Html.Raw(String.Format("{0} &copy; Copyright by Nemanja", DateTime.Now.Year));
```

Answer (score 3):

Enclose it in Html.Raw to prevent escaping.  Almost all the helpers in MVC will HTML encode content to ensure any model values that might contain HTML or scripts couldn't potentially include dangerous scripts.  Html.Raw explicitly displays the content without encoding it.

```
@Html.Raw( String.Format("{0} &copy; Copyright by Nemanja", DateTime.Now.Year) )
```